# JOLT spec - Is it possible to sort values according key/value of a list of dict?

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, dictionary, jolt

JSON Input :

```json
{
  "list": [
    {
      "tags": [
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_VM"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_HOST"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_ROLE_DNS"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_ROLE_AD"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "result_count": 1,
  "sort_by": "name"
}
```

Desired Output :

```json
{
  "role1" : "DNS",
  "role2" : "AD"
}
```

(sorting value on the last "string" after the last "_")

I already tried this but it doesnt work :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "list": {
        "*": {
          "tags": {
            "*": {
              "tag": {
                "TAG_ROLE*": "role1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Does somebody knows how to use properly JOLT ? I'm kinda lost with it

Comment: Welcome to SO, Lucas. Can you tell use why `TAG_VM` and `TAG_HOST` don't exist within the desired output, and what's the logic behind sorting? Since `AD` comes before `DNS` in alphabetical order.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. 
There is no TAG_VM and TAG_HOST in de desired output because I want to only get values that begin with "TAG_ROLE_" 
Let me explain the sorting: 
What I'm looking for is to get "AD" and "DNS" into a variable called "role1" and "role2". For example, if there was a "TAG_ROLE_QUERTY", I would have role3 = "QWERTY"
I'm only looking for this particular value starting by "TAG_ROLE_".

Comment: The title suggests the sorting is important, so I just asked for it. Now , I see that sorting is arbitary, because you seems you want to match `AD` with `role1`, and `DNS` with `role2` while it's rverse within the question, aren't they ? Excuse me, but I should know the exact rules before trying to answer.

Comment: I apologize for my bad explanations.
There is no importance if AD goes with role1 or role2. 
What matter here is that all TAG_ROLE_XXX values will be sorted into roleY = XXX. 
Y will increment for each TAG_ROLE_XXX existing.
Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's constuct it in a dynamical manner such as :

```json
[
  { // extact literals from the asterisks followed by TAG_ROLE_ through going one level up and take the value of first asterisk(already exists one, but might be more than one) by using &(1 --> level up ,1 --> first asterisk)
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "TAG_ROLE_*": {
                  "#r": "&(1,1)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // build an array, namely "r" by exchanging key-value pairs, while adding a fake first component to be used for extra increment of the index value, as indexes start from zero, but we need them to start from one in the upcoming spec 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      },
      "#0": "r"
    }
  },
  { // we tiled the key-value pairs as desired except for the one with zero key
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "role&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the first(fake) component
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*0": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: That was exaclty what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot !!
Thanks for the explanations in the code too

Comment: I have one more question. If I want to add the same patern with a different tag (TAG_XX_AB and TAG_XX_CD for example). I should add "TAG_XX_*": {"#r": "&(1,1)"                }  in the first shift. But where i should define my new variable XX1, XX2, etc.. ?

Comment: I couldn't understand what's up with `XX1`, `XX2` ... @Lucas

Comment: Can I use the "Answer Your Question" to post the JSON I want to show you ? I will delete it after

Comment: Allright, no matter @Lucas