# JOLT Spec - sort values according key/value of a list of dict

Tags: json, jolt

Follow up question to [JOLT spec - Is it possible to sort values according key/value of a list of dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814102/jolt-spec-is-it-possible-to-sort-values-according-key-value-of-a-list-of-dict/74818370#74818370)

What about adding more option :

JSON Input :

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "tags": [
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_VM"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_HOST"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_ROLE_DNS"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_ROLE_AD"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_USER_INSIDE"
        },
        {
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_USER_OUTSIDE"
        },{
          "scope": "",
          "tag": "TAG_INTERNET_TRUE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "result_count": 1,
  "sort_by": "name"
}
```

Disered Ouput:

```
{
  "role1" : "DNS",
  "role2" : "AD",
  "user1" : "INSIDE",
  "user2" : "OUTSIDE",
  "internet" : "TRUE"

}
```

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similar logic will work along with building and using multiple independent arrays by making it more dynamic this case such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "TAG_*_*": {
                  "$": "&(1,1).&(1,2)"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2"
        },
        "#0": "&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*0": ""
    }
  },
  { // exchange key-value pairs to be able to convert keys to lower case 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toLower(@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  { // exchange key-value pairs back to the original
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Ok I think i get it ! I update too late but I added a new tag "TAG_INTERNET_TRUE" to the desired output. How this one is possible to add because he has not the same patern. That will be my last question !

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Im going to vote up on both Answers. Have a great day

Comment: Wish the best for you too @Lucas